# After signing out, my firebase idToken is still valid?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following code in my firebase front-end:

```
  document.querySelector('#sign-out').addEventListener('click', () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
      document.location = '/sign-in';
    }, (error) => {
      console.error('Sign Out Error', error);
    });
  })
```

This seems to be working. I see the network request succeed, and the redirect to `/sign-in` occurs.

However, when I then navigate to `/chatroom`, I am considered logged in. My python/flask backend has the following code on the endpoint:

```
@app.route("/chatroom")
def chatroom():
    if 'idToken' in request.cookies:
        id_token = request.cookies.get("idToken")
        try:
            decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
        except:
            print("INVALID TOKEN")
            return redirect(url_for("sign_in"))

        return render_template("chatroom.html")
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("sign_in"))
```

Rather than redirecting the user to `/sign-in` when I hit this path, Firebase is verifying that the token is valid and so I am allowed to proceed, even though I had logged out.

What am I missing?

Edit:

Changed code to this for debugging purposes:

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          console.log('still signed in');
        } else {
          console.log('signed out');
        }
      });
    }, (error) => {
      console.error('Sign Out Error', error);
    });
```

It outputs `signed out`.....so I'm quite confused.

Comment: How does Firebase authentication relate to this `idToken` cookie value?

Comment: Well, the docs [said](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) that was the way to verify if a user was signed in. The cookie value is set by the front end code at the time of log-in; the value is `const idToken = await user.getIdToken();` It's just a way of communicating the token to the back end.

Comment: I guess signing out doesn't invalidate the token. If you're manually setting the cookie value, you should manually un-set it

Comment: I mean....if signing out doesn't invalidate the token, then the token couldn't be used to check if a user were signed in or not. :/ That doesn't make sense. Clearing the cookie is unrelated-- the cookie is only a way of sending the token to the backend so that backend can verify it with Firebase. The issue is that Firebase is saying it's still valid. I can force my server to think the user is logged out by removing the cookie, but that won't change the fact that the user's session is in fact still logged-in according to Firebase, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Signing out does not invalidate the token.  It just causes the SDK to forget about it, so it doesn't get refreshed or passed along to other Firebase products automatically.  The old token will be valid for up to 1 hour, until it needs to be refreshed.  If not refreshed, then it will fail verification.

If you are saving the ID token in a cookie, you should also remove it from the cookie in order to effectively sign out, so it doesn't get passed along to your backend.

Comment: How about API's? If someone uses that token to do API call. Even after logout they will be able to call API's for one hr. Is there not way in firebase to invalidate that token in firebase itself.?